# Need Help with plotting the marginal density functions of $U_1$ and $U_2$ for $\alpha_1 = 3$, $\alpha_2 = 5$ and $\beta = 2$ and its 3D Plot using R

Tags: r

Suppose that $Y_1$ has a gamma distribution with parameters $\alpha_1$ and $\beta$, that $Y_2$ is gamma distributed with parameters  $\alpha_2$ and $\beta $ , and that $Y_1$ and
$Y_2$ are independent. Let $U_1 = Y_1/(Y_1 + Y_2)$ and $U_2 = Y_1 + Y_2$.

1) Plot the marginal density functions of $U_1$ and $U_2$ for $\alpha_1 = 3$, $\alpha_2 = 5$ and $\beta = 2$ using R.

2) A more challenging question: plot the joint density of $U_1$ and $U_2$ (a 3D plot) in R.

For 1, I have the following command for $U_1$. Are they correct?

```
alpha_1=3
alpha_2=5
beta = 2
t=seq(0,1, 0.01)
den=dbeta(t,alpha_1 ,alpha_2, beta)
plot(t, den)
```

For 1, for $U_2$, i found that it is a gamma density.
however the command for this is the same as above except

> den=dgamma(t,alpha_1, alpha, beta)

R keeps complaining that do not specify both scale and rate which conflicts me... how do fix it?

Another thing that is not clear to me is the following command:
since for $U_2$ the support for $U_2$ should be bigger than 0. what is the command for infinity?

> t=seq(0,1 (this should be infinity right), 0.01)

For question 2, I type in rotate as a command to try to rotate the graph. however, the command does not work. Do I need to use some other software or there are other commands which will work?

Comment: This sounds like it should have the `self-study` [tag](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). You should not expect people to just give you code. You should *CERTAINLY* not expect someone to just give you the image that is the answer to assigned work that you clearly plan to hand in as your own. (-1)

Comment: could you give me some direction?

Comment: Please modify your question to fit with the self study guidelines

Comment: I've undone the -1 now; it's a distinct improvement.

Comment: Now, $U_{1}$ is a Beta$(\alpha_1, \alpha_2)$ distribution and $U_{2}$ a Gamma$(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2, \beta)$ distribution (shape and scale). So for plotting $U_{2}$ you could use `dgamma(t, shape = alpha_1 + alpha_2, scale = beta)`.

Comment: Another thing that is not clear to me is the following command:
since the support for $U_2$ should be bigger than 0. what is the command for infinity?
t=seq(0,1 (this should be infinity right), 0.01)

Comment: Indeed, $U_{2}$ has support $(0, \infty)$ but I don't see how you plan to plot that. `seq` generates a finite sequence and the upper limit can't be infinity. Check out the [help page](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/seq.html) for `seq`.

Comment: so what should I set the upper limit to be?

Comment: Try $60$, for example. After that, the PDF is almost $0$.

Comment: Thx...also, could you get me started on plotting the joint density of $U_1$ and $U_2$ (a 3D plot) in R?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13170/discussion-between-coolserdash-and-afsdf-dfsaf)

Comment: For question 2, I type in rotate as a command to try to rotate the graph. however, the command does not work. Do I need to use some other software or there are other commands which will work?